# C# Работа с структурами

Tags: c#

#### Задание:

1. Объявите структуру Entrant, которая представляет собой информацию о абитуриенте и содержит такие открытые поля:

   - Name – Фамилию и инициалы ;
   - IdNum – номер абитуриента;
   - CoursePoints – балы за подготовительные курсы;
   - AvgPoints – бал аттестата;
   - ZNOResults – массив структур типа ZNO;
2. Объявите структуру ZNO, которая содержит открытые поля:

   - Subject – название предмета;
   - Points – результат.
3. Для каждой структуры сделать конструкторы.
4. В структуру Entrant добавить методы (не статические):

   - GetCompMark(), который считает конкурсный бал абитуриента. Если он писал меньше 3 предметов возвращать 0, если больше, то считать только первые три
   - GetBestSubject(), что возвращает название предмета который студент написал лучше всех ;
   - GetWorstSubject() - хуже всех.
5. В классе Program предусмотреть статические методы:

   - ReadEntrantsArray() – читает с клавиатуры массив структур (n штук) и возвращает массив структур типа Entrant;
   - PrintEntrant() – принимает структуру типа Entrant и выводит на экран;

Вот именно что у меня не получается: я не уверен правильно ли я объявил это все дело. С методами беда, ибо примеров использования вложенного массива структур я нигде не нашел. Вот сам код:

```
namespace StructConlsole
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void ReadEnterantsArray(int n)
        {
            int re = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine($"Введіть прізвище та ініціали {i} абітурієнта =");
                enterants[i].name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine($"Введіть ідентифікаційний код {i} абітурієнта =");
                if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out enterants[i].idNum))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Помилка введення значення. Будь-ласка повторіть введення значення ще раз!");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Введіть бали за підготовчі курси =");
                if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out enterants[i].coursePoints))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Помилка введення значення. Будь-ласка повторіть введення значення ще раз!");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Введіть бал атестату =");
                if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out enterants[i].avgPoints))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Помилка введення значення. Будь-ласка повторіть введення значення ще раз!");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Кількість предметів ЗНО =");
                if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out results[i].kpred))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Помилка введення значення. Будь-ласка повторіть введення значення ще раз!");
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < results[i].kpred; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Введіть назву предмета =");
                    results[re].subject = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Введіть результат =");
                    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out results[re].points))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Помилка введення значення. Будь-ласка повторіть введення значення ще раз!");
                    }
                    re++;
                }

            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
                        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;

            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;

            Console.WriteLine("Введіть кількість абітурієнтів =");
            if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int n))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Помилка введення значення. Будь-ласка повторіть введення значення ще раз!");
            }

            ReadEnterantsArray(n);
            PrintEntrant(n);

            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        public static Entrant[] enterants = new Entrant[100];
        public static ZNO[] results = new ZNO[100];

        public static void PrintEntrant(int n)
        {
            int ra = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine($"Абітурієнт №{i} ---{enterants[i].name}" +
                    $"Індифікаційний код абітурієнта--- {enterants[i].idNum}" +
                    $"Набрав {enterants[i].coursePoints} балів за підготовчі курси" +
                    $"Бал його атестату --- {enterants[i].avgPoints}");
                for ( int j=0; j < results[i].kpred; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Набрав {results[ra].points} " +
                        $"балів з предмету {results[ra].subject}");
                    ra++;
                }

            }
        }

        public static void SortEntrantsByPoints(int n)
        {

        }

        public struct Entrant
        {
            public string name;
            public int idNum;
            public int coursePoints;
            public int avgPoints;
            public ZNO[] ZNOResults;
            public int compMark;

            public Entrant(string na, int i, int c, int a, ZNO[] j,int cm)
            {

                name = na;
                idNum = i;
                coursePoints = c;
                avgPoints = a;
                ZNOResults = j;
                compMark = cm;
            }
            public Entrant(ZNO[] j)
            {

                name = "Anon";
                idNum = 228;
                coursePoints = 1337;
                avgPoints = 228;
                ZNOResults = j;
                compMark = 2;
            }
        }

        public struct ZNO
        {
            public string subject;
            public int points;
            public int kpred;

            public ZNO(string sub, int p, int k)
            {
                subject = sub;
                points = p;
                kpred = k;
            }
            public ZNO(string sub)
            {
                subject = "Dont know";
                points = 3;
                kpred = 1;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Выглядит неплохо, но возможно вам нужна инспекция кода?

Comment: @Foggy Finder да. Еще я так и не разобрался с этими методами.

Comment: нет, инспекция это когда вы хотите получить обзор своего кода (в том числе содержащий критику), но если у вас проблема с реализацией какого-то метода это совсем другое дело

Comment: @Foggy Finder ну для начала инспекцию, а потом уже отталкиваясь от нее посмотрю. Ведь часто бывает что изначально код неправильный.

Comment: откуда у вас kpred в ZNO? Нет такого в задании. Структуры у вас худо-бедно описаны, там есть к чему придраться (кодстайл), но будем считать, что есть. А вот какая формула для GetCompMark?Как её считать, сумму, среднее? Как вы пункт 4 собирались делать, где код, какие сложности?

Comment: по первых, С# это вам не С, вот так `public static Entrant[] enterants = new Entrant[100];
        public static ZNO[] results = new ZNO[100];` (с запасом) объявлять не надо возможно кто-то захочет вставить больше число записей а вы окажитесь к такому не готовы

Comment: вот такой конструктор `public ZNO(string sub)
            {
                subject = "Dont know";` не имеет смысла, так как вы нигде не присваиваете `sub`

Comment: @A K (коэффициент первого предмета 0.25 , второго - 0.4, третьего - 0.2 ) + (бал аттестата* 0.1) + (подготовительные курсы*0.05)